# How do I stop transmission-daemon?

Tags: services, transmission, init.d

How do  I stop transmission-daemon?

I've ran `sudo /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop` and after a while I get confirmation that it completed `[ OK ]`:

```
greg@VManage:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop  
 * Stopping bittorrent daemon transmission-daemon                       [ OK ]
```

but if I immediately run `ps aux | grep transm` I see that transmission-daemon is still running.

```
greg@VManage:~$ ps aux | grep trans
122       5047  0.2  0.0 246264  3604 ?        Ssl  15:12   0:00 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --config-dir /var/       lib/transmission-daemon/info
greg      5079  0.0  0.0  13648   944 pts/1    S+   15:12   0:00 grep --color=auto trans
```

**** Updated ****

I've also tried `kill`ing the process but this has no effect:

```
greg@VManage:~$ ps aux | grep trans
122       5047  0.0  0.0 250400  3744 ?        Ssl  15:12   0:00 /usr/bin/transm                                                            ission-daemon -f --config-dir /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info
greg     14706  0.0  0.0  13648   944 pts/2    S+   15:49   0:00 grep --color=au                                                            to trans
greg@VManage:~$ sudo kill -9 5047
[sudo] password for greg:
greg@VManage:~$ ps aux | grep trans
122      14795  0.1  0.0 246264  3600 ?        Ssl  15:49   0:00 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --config-dir /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info
greg     14847  0.0  0.0  13648   948 pts/2    S+   15:49   0:00 grep --color=auto trans
greg@VManage:~$ sudo kill -9 14795
greg@VManage:~$ ps aux | grep trans
122      14896  0.5  0.0 246264  3552 ?        Ssl  15:50   0:00 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --config-dir /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info
greg     14912  0.0  0.0  13648   948 pts/2    S+   15:50   0:00 grep --color=auto trans
```

It looks like the process is being killed but it's being restarted, not the new PID in the 2nd and 3rd calls to `ps aux`.

Comment: fast way `sudo kill -9 122`.

Comment: @2707974 I tried that as well but no joy.

Comment: We are wrong. PID is 5047. `sudo kill -9 5047`

Comment: Usually, `sudo service transmission-daemon stop`.

Comment: @mikewhatever thanks, that did it. Post as an answer and I'll give you the marks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`sudo service transmission-daemon stop` is the way to go.

Comment: but why?! and how is it staying alive? is this some upstart wizardry?

Comment: It probably re-spawns, as per the startup script: `/etc/init/transmission-daemon.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

Enter    `sudo service transmission-daemon stop` into a terminal

See: [TransmissionHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo)

Answer (score 1):

sudo cp -f /etc/default/transmission-daemon /etc/default/transmission-daemon.old
    sudo echo "ENABLE_DAEMON=0" > /etc/default/transmission-daemon && \
    sudo service transmission-daemon stop